# C# Recuperar todos os botões dinâmicos

Tags: c#

Estou com um projeto em C# e estou com dificuldades.

Preciso recuperar os dados dos botões gerados dinamicamente ao mesmo tempo.
No projeto existem aproximadamente 50 botões para abrir formulários diferentes em um painel e quando clico em um botão queria que eles mudesem de cor e que todos os outros 49 botões fiquem transparentes, mais como eles são gerados dinamicamente não consegui, será que tem como realizar um chamado simultaneo para esse botões que devem ficar transparentes?
Quando utilizo o sender só consigo recuperar um botão por vez. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: pq nao usar o TabControl ?

Answer (score 0):

você pode percorrer todos os botões do form, usando um foreach.
Fiz um exemplo que você pode adaptar à sua situação;

Evite postar print do código, mostre o código formatado e de preferência completo (na parte que interessa) de forma que possamos reproduzir o mesmo código para uma resposta.

Segue exemplo:

```
for (int i =1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Tag = i;
    b.Text = "Button " + i;
    b.Name = "btn" + i;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
    b.Click += (ss, ee) => { 
    
        foreach (Button btn in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (btn == b)
                btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            else
                btn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    
    };
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs. O primeiro botão usei para chamar esse código, e está fora do flowLayoutPanel, então não entrou no loop.

Comment: Realmente é melhor colocar todo o código aqui então vou editar a pegunta pra melhor entender meu problema OK

Comment: acho q mudou completamente a questão da pergunta inicial, não sei nem se deixo a resposta aqui rs...

Comment: Verdade Rovann é que é a primeira vez que posto aqui. Você acha melhor apagar a pergunta e começar outra com as duas dúvidas separadas?

Comment: dá uma lida nos materiais da comunidade de como perguntar, como não perguntar e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?cb=1